# JS Add class to element - using parent/child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask how can i add class to element, but using nested navigation. Structure of HTML:

```
<form class="searchboxATM">
    <input name="submit_search" value="OK" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
</form>
```

I can't simply use `getElementsByClassName("btn");` because there is many more `.btn` elements which i dont want to change. How can i do it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where and when you want to add class? then comes _How_ So answer question first

Comment: How about `$('.searchboxATM input[type="submit"]')` or ``$('.searchboxATM input[name="submit_search"]')``?

Comment: Satpal - i can't modify HTML

Answer (score 1):

In **pure JS**, you can use `querySelector`:

[querySelector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector(".searchboxATM .btn");
```

Or you can **add a specific id** to your input:

```
<form class="searchboxATM">
    <input name="submit_search" id="submitSearch" value="OK" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
</form>
```

and use `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById("submitSearch");
```

Or a **query selector on the id**:

```
document.querySelector("#submitSearch");
```

Or use `getElementsByName`:

```
document.getElementsByName("submit_search")[0]
```

If you want to use **JQuery**, you just have to use `$` instead of `document.querySelector` :

```
$("#submitSearch")
```

Or

```
$(".searchboxATM .btn")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$(".searchboxATM .btn")` if it works for you.